# How to prevent interrupted mv moving data

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, mv

On Ubuntu 18.04 I am running a small PHP web application which moves directories one by one with nested dirs and files from one filesystem to another via `exec(mv filepath)` method.

Now I have the problem that when a nested directory or file is missing read rights or is somehow corrputed the `mv` fails (because it cannot delete the file in the **src**). But at that point the data is already moved into **dest**.

Which means in the end I have a fully copied dir in **dest** and still the dir in **src** but only with the dirs/files which have invalid permission or are corrupted. I do not want this behaviour. As soon as the `mv` fails for whatever reason it should revert the whole process/leave **src** as it was.

In my PHP Script I already check if the `mv` fails. If yes I could then check if the dir exists in **dest** and `mv` back to **src**.

But is there no better/easier way to achieve this bahaviour?

Comment: 1) copy; 2) remove if copy worked.

Comment: @Toto I think `cp` is removing the timestamp right? I want to keep these.

Comment: Use option `--preserve`, see: http://www.unixcl.com/2009/02/linux-copy-file-and-preserve-timestamp.html